# Haskell Hashtable Performance

Tags: haskell, hashmap

I am trying to use hash tables in Haskell with the [`hashtables` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables), and finding that I cannot get anywhere near Python's performance. How can I achieve similar performance? Is it possible given current Haskell libraries and compilers? If not, what's the underlying issue?

Here is my Python code:

```
y = {}
for x in xrange(10000000):
    y[x] = x
print y[100]
```

Here's my corresponding Haskell code:

```
import qualified Data.HashTable.IO as H
import Control.Monad

main = do
  y <- H.new :: IO (H.CuckooHashTable Int Int)
  forM_ [1..10000000] $ \x -> H.insert y x x
  H.lookup y 100 >>= print
```

Here is another version using `Data.Map`, which is slower than both for me:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.List
import Control.Monad
main = do
  let m = foldl' (\m x -> Map.insert x x m) Map.empty [1..10000000]
  print $ Map.lookup 100 m
```

Interestingly enough, `Data.HashMap` performs very badly:

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as Map
import Data.List
main = do
  let m = foldl' (\m x -> Map.insert x x m) Map.empty [1..10000000]
  print $ Map.lookup 100 m
```

My suspicion is that `Data.HashMap` performs badly because unlike `Data.Map`, it is not spine-strict (I think), so `foldl'` is just a `foldl`, with the associated thunk buildup problems.

Note that I have used `-prof` and verified that the majority of the time is spend in the `hashtables` or `Data.Map` code, not on the `forM` or anything like that. All code is compiled with `-O2` and no other parameters.

Comment: What times are you getting?

Comment: Using `new`, the times are 2 and 10-15 seconds; using `newSized` as suggested in the answer below, they are 2 and 4.

Comment: FYI- I just tried it on my machine....  about 10 seconds for the `Data.HashTable.IO` code, about 1 second for the python, and 3 seconds for `Data.Map`.

Comment: What is your `Data.Map` code? I've put some code into the question and it's getting about 8 seconds (whereas the IO version gets 3-4).

Comment: Hash table design requires balancing various factors. It's worth pointing out that inserting a long linear sequence of data is almost opposite to the general use case of hash tables, and that being so artificial may favour one implementation over another for the wrong reasons. However, aquiring a suitable random set of data to test them against each other risks measuring the wrong bit of code.

Comment: That's a very good point, especially for `Data.Map` which uses `Ord`. So, is this simply a case of the available Haskell libraries not being on par with the Python heavily-optimized dictionaries?

Comment: `Data.Map` and `Data.HashMap` both provide persistent containers, i.e. use non-destructive updates. I'd put them in a different category.

Comment: Why use `Data.Map` instead of `Data.IntMap` which is specialized for integer keys?

Comment: @AndrewGibiansky I mean that a hash table well optimised for general use might perform badly for non-random data, so testing with a linear set of data might artificially slow things down. (Conversely a hash table that accepts linear data quickly might perform badly when there are collisions.) You're not testing normal performance at the moment, so you can't tell how fast it will perform under normal conditions. (eg If you tested simple quicksort with reversed data you'd get an inaccurate picture of its typical performance. If you insert linear data into a tree, you get worst-case performance.)

Comment: (Your Map and HashMap code don't specify `Int` so will have defaulted to the larger and slower arbitrary precision `Integer`.)

Answer (score 11):

As reddit.com/u/cheecheeo suggested [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2le78y/haskell_hash_table_performance_question/), using [Data.Judy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/judy-0.2.3/docs/Data-Judy.html), you'll get similar performance for your particular microbenchmark:

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.Judy as J
import Control.Monad (forM_)

main = do
    h <- J.new :: IO (J.JudyL Int)
    forM_ [0..10000000] $ \i -> J.insert (fromIntegral i) i h
    v <- J.lookup 100 h
    putStrLn $ show v
```

Timeing the above:

```
$ time ./Main
Just 100

real    0m0.958s
user    0m0.924s
sys     0m0.032s
```

Timing the python code of OP:

```
$ time ./main.py
100

real    0m1.067s
user    0m0.886s
sys     0m0.180s
```

Answer (score 9):

The documentation for [`hashtables`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables) notes that "Cuckoo hashing, like the basic hash table implementation using linear probing, can suffer from long delays when the table is resized." You use `new`, which creates a new table of the default size. [From looking at the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables-1.1.2.1/docs/src/Data-HashTable-ST-Cuckoo.html#new), it appears that the default size is 2. Inserting 10000000 items likely entails numerous resizings.

Try using `newSized`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This helps dramatically. If I use `newSized` with exactly the right number of elements, the Python code and the Haskell code only differ by 2x in speed. Are there any other tricks that may help?

Answer (score 2):

Given the times above, I thought I would throw in the `Data.Map` solution, which seems to be comparable to using newSized.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

main = do
       print $ M.lookup 100 $ M.fromList $ map (\x -> (x,x)) [1..10000000]
```

Comment: This is also a solution, but I think it doesn't quite accurately reflect the original code, as the point is that we are doing repeated insertions and don't have all the data up front. But this is still a useful data point.

Comment: @AndrewGibiansky, I think you are referring to `fromList`.  But if you look at the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/src/Data-Map.html#fromList), you can see that `fromList` is just implemented as a fold of insertions.

Comment: On my platform forcing the list to `::[Int]` yields a 13% speedup (8.5 s to 7.4s) with `Data.Map.Lazy` outperforming `Data.Map.Strict`, but switching to an IntMap makes this faster by a factor of 2 and the winner is `Data.IntMap.Strict` at 3.5s. You can actually get even faster with `fromDistinctAscList` (2.2s) but as Andrew points out that's probably cheating as the benchmark resembles real-world usage less.

Comment: I see a slight speedup (~10%) on the IntMaps by asking GHC to use its LLVM backend, but it's not much. By comparison, python runs in 1.371s, so it's still faster. The same speedup seems to come when I unroll the `fromList $ map` stuff into an accumulator loop with `M.insert` and might be due to cons-cell reallocations or something.